# ¿Cómo concatenar datos de dos filas diferentes si se cumple una condición?

Tags: python, csv

No sé si está bien formulada mi pregunta pero tengo el siguiente problema; tengo varios archivos en formato csv con la siguiente estructura:

[image: Estructura inicial]

Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando encuentre en la primera columna diferente de "NOTAXX" y diferente de vacio, lo concatene en la columna NOTAS(E) del renglon anterior, siempre y cuando el renglon anterior inicie con la columna igual a "NOTAXX" no sé si me explico? Lo que necesito es que quede de la siguente manera:

[image: Estructura deseada]

Estoy utilizando Python ya que tengo que procesar archivos con al rededor de 300,000 registros y pensar hacerlo en Excel es tardar mucho tiempo, pero estoy abierto a cualquier alternativa (php, java, bash, etc), actualmente tengo entendido que se puede hacer con 2 ciclos for pero estoy perdido y atorado, ya no encuentro qué hacer =(

Comment: has puesto muchos lenguajes, ¿intentaste algo con alguno? Por otra parte, sería bueno proporcionar los ejemplos en texto y ofrecer un [mcve] claro para poder entender el problema a la perfección

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este script en Python 3 podría servir:

```
import re
import sys

buffer = ""
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    if line != "":
        if re.search("^NOTA\d\d", line):
            if buffer != "":
                print(buffer)
            buffer = line
        else:
            buffer = line if buffer == "" else buffer + " " + line

if buffer != "":
    print(buffer)
```

---

Este script lee la entrada estándar línea por línea ignorando líneas vacías y escribe en la salida estándar.

Cuando se itera sobre `sys.stdin` las líneas leídas tienen un salto de línea (`\n`) al final que se puede eliminar con `rstrip("\n")`. `buffer` almacena las líneas leídas hasta que se encuentra una línea que comienza por `NOTA\d\d` (expresión regular, `^` indica el comienzo de la línea). Cuando una línea de estas se encuentra, se imprime el contenido de `buffer` y la línea leída se almacena en esta. Cuando se encuentra una línea no vacía que no comienza por `NOTA\d\d`, esta se concatena a `buffer`, agregando un espacio en caso de que `buffer` no esté vacía.

Si al terminar de leer la entrada estándar `buffer` no está vacía, se imprime.

Asumiendo que los datos están en un archivo llamado `data.csv` y el script en un archivo `script.py`, este script se podría ejecutar en bash usando `cat data.csv | python3 script.py`.

Si usar la entrada y salida estándar no es una opción se podría leer de y escribir a un archivo en su lugar. Para esto se podría usar la función `open()` y el parámetro `file` de la función `print()` así:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as output:
    with open("data.csv", "r") as input:
        for line in input:
            
            # ...
            
            print(buffer, file = output)
    
    # ...
```

Comment: Gracias me funciona bien, lo ejecuto así `cat data.csv | python3 script.py > salida.csv` intenté hacerlo por medio de open() pero no me funciona, otra cosa, estaba viendo la salida y me cambia ciertos caracteres (como la letra 'ñ'), ya intenté con esta línea de código: `sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` pero sigue cambiándome los caracteres